# Unable to delete remote branch although it seems to exist

Tags: git

Below is the image showing the problem which pretty much explains everything. I am not sure why I can't delete these. Any ideas ?

Both:

```
git push origin --delete origin/devArif

git push origin --delete remotes/origin/devArif
```

do not work

[image]

Comment: try `git fetch --prune`

Comment: @atamanroman that worked perfectly. `prune remote-tracking branches no longer on remote` Please post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you ;)

Comment: See my answer, I hope it makes it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git fetch --prune` to delete remote branches which do not exist on the remote anymore.

You can't delete `origin/devArif` (you pushed, hence it's a remote operation) because it does not exists on `origin`.

To delete the local information that on some point in time a branch `devArif` existed on `origin`, you need to do `fetch --prune`, which syncs your known remote branches with the state on `origin`.

If someone deletes a branch on a remote that information won't automatically replicate downstream (same with tags). If you delete that branch on remote yourself (`git push origin :devArif`), that happens automatically for your repo only.